# Markov chain simulations including permutations

Tags: probability, markov-chains, simulation

Let $S_n$ be the set of all permutations of $\{1,2,...,n\}$ and $$S_{k,n}=\left\{\sigma=(\sigma(1),...,\sigma(n)) \in \mathcal{S}_n : \sum \limits_{j=1}^{n}j\sigma(j)\geq k\right\}$$ for a $k\in \mathbb{N}$ such that $S_{k,n}\neq \emptyset$.

I want to construct an irreducible Markov chain on $S_{k,n}$ which has a uniform distribution on $S_{k,n}$ as a stationary distribution in order to use it for simulation.

What are good methods to do so?

Comment: Metropolis-Hastings might be a good idea here.
Since any permutation can be written as a product of transpositions the reference probability kernel could be given by the uniform distribution on those permutations that deviate by at most one transposition from the current state. This would certainly work for the uniform distribution on $S_n$ and i am pretty sure it can be adapted to $S_{k,n}$ by slightly changing the reference kernel. More simply you could generate uniform samples in $S_n$ and discard those samples that are not in $S_{nk}$.

Comment: Thank you. I thought about Metropolis-Hastings too, but I am not that firm with the algorithm, could you eloborate? (Only if it isn't too much work)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To elaborate my comment further:

### Metropolis-Hastings with finite state space

Let $E$ be a finite state space with the usual $\sigma$-algebra. Since $E$ is finite we can identify probability measures on $E$ with non-negative vectors that sum to 1 and probability kernels on $E$ with non-negative matrices whose columns sum to 1.

Let $q$ be the reference probability kernel on $E$ and $\pi$ the positive target distribution.
Then the Metropolis-Hastings kernel is defined by
\begin{equation}
    p(x,y)  = 
    \begin{cases}
        q (x,y) \min \big \{ \frac{\pi (y) q(y , x)}{ \pi (x) q(x, y)}, 1 \big \}, \ \text{if} \ q(x,y) \neq 0 \ \text{and} \ x \neq y,\\ 
        0, \ \text{if} \ q(x,y) =0 \ \text{and} \ x \neq y,\\ 
        1 - \sum_{z \neq x} p(x,z) \ \text{if} \ x=y,
    \end{cases}
\end{equation}
for $x,y \in E$.
The intuitive meaning is that $p(x,y)$ is the probability to transition from the state $x$ to the state $y$.
Also note that $\pi$ is a stationary distribution of $p$ because $p$ and $\pi$ satisfy the detailed balance condition.

### Application to the uniform distribution on $S_n$

To apply this construction to the case of interest let $E=S_n$ and $\pi$ be the uniform distribution on $E$. Define the reference kernel $q$ on $E$ by
$$q(x,y) = \begin{cases}
1/L, \quad \text{if there exist a transposition $T$ so that $y=Tx$}\\
0, \quad \text{else},
\end{cases}$$
where $L = \frac{n^2}{2}$ is the number of different transpositions (counting the identity as a transposition).
Now $p$ is irreducible and aperiodic and so the distribution of any Markov chain with state space $E$ and transition kernel $p$ will converge to $\pi$.

Then all that is left is to construct a Markov-Chain using the computer that has the Metropolis-Hastings kernel as a transition kernel. Note that this Markov-Chain will be trivial in a certain sense, because $\pi$ is the uniform distribution.

We can then use that Markov-Chain to sample from $S_{n,k}$ by throwing away the samples that do not meet the condition or slightly modify the existing solution for $S_n$.